# French keyboard locked in QWERTY

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, internationalization, qwerty

in other apps on my phone I can change from English-QWERTY to Smileys to French-AZERTY keyboards.

My iPhone 6 is set in English language.

In the app I am coding, for iOS7 and newer, I can not change to AZERTY, when I change to French the Keyboard stay in QWERTY :

[image]

Why? And how to solve it?

Thanks